# ajax jquery post example error 503

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-503

When i click run button show this error in chrome console and don't alert anything

```
POST http://mysite/gd/add.php 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

[image]

index.php

```
<html>
<head>   
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
 <script>
function go(){  
$.ajax({ url: 'add.php',
         data: {'q': ''},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
         alert(output);}
});
}
 </script>
 <button onclick="go();">Run</button>
</body>
</html>
```

add.php

```
<?php echo "Hello"; ?>
```

Comment: You are using php in cgi and php is not working/crashed

Comment: if you type in your browser http://mysite/gd/add.php does it work?

Comment: How i can get data from php page through ajax?

Comment: one time alert and one time show error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code in local environment, it is working fine. The reason for 503 error because of the Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some delay. Some servers in this state may also simply refuse the socket connection, in which case a different error may be generated because the socket creation timed out. 

user2511140 : I add this code to show errors.my server is to busy and show error.i changed server and problem solved

```
$.ajax({ url: 'add.php',
         type: 'post',
         data: {'q': ''},
         success: function(output) {
         alert(output);},
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);},
});
}
```

Comment: on local works fine.but when i upload to my server and run it showing error.Is related to my server?

Comment: Yes. In your screenshots itslef showing like service unavailable.

Comment: @user2511140 Please check your `.htaccess` configuration and file permission. All file must be in `644` permission

Comment: files has 644 permission

Comment: then how about `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: also for `.htaccess` (permission ,rename and delete)

Answer (score 1):

so i know it is old, but i just solved this problem while working on a wordpress project. I got the same error message, because there was a difference between the Url of the admin-ajax - script, written in the header(www.url.de/admin-ajax.ph) - and the url to load the data from (www.urx.de/ajax.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call with `http://mysite/gd/add.php` or `gd/add.php` URL

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://mysite/gd/add.php',
         data: {'q': ''},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
         alert(output);}
});
```

If above code is not working. Please check your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Did you configured the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @user2511140 I not sure. please remove or rename the `.htaccess` file and check once again. and check your files permission also

Answer (score 0):

Your current page is `a.php` and you send ajax request to `add.php`, so check whether they both are in same directory or not?

If so then try following or else try absolute HTTP path.

```
$.ajax({ url: './add.php',
         data: {'q': ''},
         type: 'POST',
         success: function(output) {
             alert(output);
         }
});
```

Comment: @user2511140 Are you doing this on localhost or in live website? I mean some PHP/server configuration causing the issue!

Comment: on local works fine.but when i upload to my server and run it showing error.Is related to my server?

Comment: @user2511140 Yes, it might because of server load much higher, also service stopped or paused. Please post same question on serverfault.com with server configurations.

Comment: @user2511140 I regret, but I have not enough time and no one is with me to do this.